# Deleted right before I could answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Arg, few things irritate me more than questions that are deleted (by owner) right before I post an answer. After reading the question, I'm writing or modifying a piece of code, testing it, typing some explanation, and right in that process, sometimes even when I press the post button, I get the notification that the question is deleted.

Voting to undelete the question doesn't often help that much, and in a way I think I should respect that OP deletes the question. Still it annoys me, and I feel my efforts have gone to waste.

It also makes it tempting to post a short answer quickly to reduce the risk of OP deleting the question, although I feel I shouldn't have to.

How do you handle this situation?

Comment: Hit the gym, hit a pillow, hit the "New Tab" link to open YouTube to watch puppies to take my mind off of that...

Comment: It is annoying, but there isn't much one can do. Being a fastest gun in the west can help sometimes - but then often there's no way to contribute anything meaningful right away

Comment: This happens to me too. Maybe it shouldn't be possible to delete your own non-negative scored question in the first (say) 15 minutes of its life.

Comment: You, or the question, also need an upvote. Does "I can answer this question?" automatically means you'll vote it up?

Comment: @Jongware Why does the question need an upvote? The OP can still delete an upvoted question. Otherwise, how would one get the Disciplined badge? (A short answer would, indeed, need an upvote to prevent deletion by the OP.)

Comment: *Deal with it!* <- As hard as it sounds, that's just reality. It also happens to me and I also had answers, where I put a lot of effort into them and OP just delete it. But I think you just have to close the tab and don't care about it anymore as hard as it sounds. (<- And for me that's also very hard to do, so you are not alone here! :)

Comment: @Kendra: you're right – only being FGITW is not enough, it has to stick as well.

Answer (score 6):

> *"Voting to undelete the question doesn't often help that much, and in a way I think I should respect that OP deletes the question. Still it annoys me, and I feel my efforts have gone to waste."*

Yes, sadly. Respect OP's will to delete their own question primarily.

If there's a question deleted from other users (or even a particular mod) as the original OP, you may consider to vote for undeletion, if you have serious doubts why the question was deleted.

You can even place a mod attention flag, and explain further, why you think the question/answer should be *undeleted*.