# Poster deleting their own good question

Tags: discussion, questions, deleted-questions

Many times I've been in a situation where I start to write an answer for a *good* question. But the question is deleted by its poster before anyone got the time to answer.

The user most likely found the answer himself. But I still think it makes sense for that question to be visible for others.

What should I do in this situation? Do I "steal" the question by asking it myself then adding my own answer? Or should I try to contact the user to ask him for an undelete?

I don't think this is a duplicate, as other question are talking about *bad* deleted questions. But I'm asking for *good* question instead, those who don't need any edit.

Comment: I shouldn't have accepted the  "potential duplicate" : This doesn't answer the question. As in this question, the question was _bad_. While in my case, the question was good. No edit required at all.

Comment: How about this dupe then? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299326/215552 :)

Comment: Hum, this one say we should flag for undelete. But I don't have the rights. I can't even see the question

Comment: It says a bit more than that. How about the second sentence: "Respect OP's will to delete their own question primarily." Certainly that's something you can do at your reputation?

Comment: Sure. But at the same time, I think the question belong to stackoverflow. And just plaining asking it again without improvement isn't respecting the OP's will either.

Comment: Simply flag for mod, or if you can't view the question but still have the link, you might want to consider bringing it up on meta or SOCVR for review. Please ensure the question is a good candidate for undeletion before you involve a mod however.

Comment: As a side note, I've also found this one : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305619/when-should-we-overturn-an-owners-decision-to-delete-their-question?rq=1